# Hive terminal takes long time to launch

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql, mapr

My hadoop cluster is used by many users and there are 1000 of databases in hive.
 We are recently observing huge time delay in launching hive terminal. When I change hive log level to INFO `--hiveconf hive.root.logger=INFO,console`, I see so many background tasks running, below are the sample log lines from console-

```
INFO Persistence: Property datanucleus.fixedDatastore unknown - will be ignored
INFO Persistence: Property hive.metastore.integral.jdo.pushdown unknown - will be ignored
INFO Persistence: Property datanucleus.cache.level2 unknown - will be ignored
INFO ObjectStore: Setting MetaStore object pin classes with hive.metastore.cache.pinobjtypes="Table,StorageDescriptor,SerDeInfo,Partition,Database,Type,FieldSchema,Order"
INFO MetaStoreDirectSql: Using direct SQL, underlying DB is MYSQL
INFO ObjectStore: Initialized ObjectStore
INFO HiveMetaStore: Added admin role in metastore
INFO HiveMetaStore: Added public role in metastore
INFO HiveMetaStore: No user is added in admin role, since config is empty
INFO HiveMetaStore: 0: get_all_databases
INFO audit: ugi=xxxxx        ip=unknown-ip-addr      cmd=get_all_databases
INFO HiveMetaStore: 0: get_functions: db=0as72_c102_4we1e_ac3_46d9192 pat=*
INFO audit: ugi=xxxxx        ip=unknown-ip-addr      cmd=get_functions: db=as72_c102_4we1e_ac3_46d9192 pat=*
INFO HiveMetaStore: 0: get_functions: db=10065_db pat=*
```

**Hive version:** 1.2

Is there any parameter which I can set to avoid loading this as they aren't related to my database? Thanks

Comment: What is a _"Hive terminal"_ -- the legacy `hive` CLI (deprecated fat client)? `beeline` (JDBC thin client)? something else?

Comment: `beeline` has a command line option that is explicit enough: `--fastConnect=true` (but that's the default setting anyway...)